# How to poll an app / process CPU utilization levels with fine granularity in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, command-line, cpu, activity-monitor, monitoring

I have a particularly problematic process in macOS that has a CPU utilization of 50-100% rather consistently. The process seems to have a somewhat high variability depending on several variables.

Unfortunately one of the variables is Activity Monitor and consequently I'd like to use a Terminal / shell based method to poll the process in question at differing rates from extremely high frequency to lower frequency as I begin to isolate some issues.

How can a process be monitored in terms of CPU utilization at varying frequency from the shell?

Comment: Is this a program you have made yourself, or possibly one that you have access to the source code for? - It sounds like a bad idea to diagnose problem by monitoring CPU utilization externally with a tool like that - it sounds like you would benefit much more from simply profiling the program.

Comment: No, it is a third party program and part of macOS and Apple simply has not offered any help in the situation for two years after about 15 reports through the dev program and so forth. The bottom line is that CPU utilization does vary based on certain parameters and I need to poll CPU usage for this specific process. I suppose I'm going to have to do something very brute-force'ish such as grabbing info from `top` and teasing out the important field, but I was hoping to find a more targeted and efficient method.

Comment: The dev program is the wrong place to contact. You do not want to use top - just profile the program. Can you give out more details about what the program specifically is, and what the actual problem are? If not, it’s really hard to offer much help

Comment: I just want to poll the CPU usage. I really don't need to give more info about it, but with your insistence it's `WindowServer` @jksoegaard.

Comment: Just to understand - you're saying that you know best how to diagnose this problem, and only want help regarding the method you have chosen, and do not want any tips on better methods that would help you solve your problem?

Comment: You've got it, correct @jksoegaard.

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll implement it myself if I don't get an answer. I actually know how to do this roughly, I just don't have a lot of time to poke about for the next several days and hoped to short circuit the effort. EDIT: Oh, thanks, I see you threw an answer out - appreciate it! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the task of getting the CPU utilization of WindowServer at any given frequency, you can just run this command with that frequency:

```
ps -o pcpu -p $(pgrep WindowServer)
```

You have not defined what you mean by "extremely high frequency" and "lower frequency", so you have to make sure yourself that those frequencies lie within the range where it is reasonable to use a command such as the above.

You have asked that we do not recommend solutions that are better suited for solving the actual problem, so I won't do that.

Comment: This is wonderful and has already helped a bunch to tweak a few things and isolate some problem scenarios. `watch -n 0.5 ps -o pcpu -p $(pgrep WindowServer)` (obviously changing the `0.5` to whatever frequency that's helpful is fantastic and has been much more accurate than `Activity Monitor.app`. I may do a bit more with it in terms of averaging and feeding it into a script, but this is spot on - appreciate it!

Comment: As you are able to implement this yourself, according to your earlier comment, I assume you already know what's skewing your results in using the command like this. Hope you get your problem fixed!

Comment: Thanks, as I also explained and important in consideration is simply time and research vs reality. There's a balance that has to be struck and I appreciate your having helped to reduce the time in this particular situation. Indeed, like I mentioned, I have identified some issues and now have added it to my Apple bug reports as well so hopefully we see a more robust addressing of the issues.